# How to code customized pickers in a class of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipickerview

I’d like to code a view (popup – window) including two picker on it in order to enter weeks (of Year) and years with two separate picker views. Firstly, I started by creating a new class as subclass of UIView. Next up, I coded the windows, which should pop up, in case it is called. 
Now I’ve the problem, that I can’t fill my two picker views with data, as UIView does not support UIPickerViewDataSource. 
How can I solve that problem, as I only want to show it as a small pop up and not open an entire UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be a controller, displayed in a popover.

The presenter should be UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate with overridden method to support popovers on iPhone (by default, they are gonna be presented modally).

```
extension ItemViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
   func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
     return .None
   }
}
```

Use this method to present your picker controller:

```
func instantiatePicker(picker: UIViewController, sender: UIView) {
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    let ppc = picker.popoverPresentationController!
    ppc.delegate = self
    ppc.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    ppc.sourceView = sender
    ppc.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In your picker controller override this property to adjust popover size to your desire, like that:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        return CGSize(width: datePicker.bounds.width, height: datePicker.bounds.height + anotherPicker.bounds.height)
    }
    set {
        super.preferredContentSize = newValue
    }
}
```